# Как получить адрес несуществующего файла для ErrorDocument 404

Tags: .htaccess

Первая проблема решено, осталась вторая:
Добавил в 404.php: `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` однако **echo** ничего не выводит.

Как получить адрес несуществующего файла, чтобы вывести его на 404.php?

Содержимое **.htaccess**:

```
#
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
#
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
#
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: стоит показать htaccess

Comment: Добавил, но он очень прост...

Comment: А файл '404.html' в корне есть? Открывается в браузере? (и index.cgi стоит убрать, если не используется)

Comment: Да, `ErrorDocument 403 /404.html` например работает

Comment: Причём тут 403? httр//сайт.ру/404.html  - показывает содержимое этой страницы (404.html)?

Comment: О! тут пришло в голову. Это не бесплатный хостинг? Может хостер не даёт переназначить 404 ответ.

Comment: 403 это для примера. Это средний хостинг. Не знаю, какой им резон делать 500 ошибку вместо 404 :)

Comment: если хочется получить помощь - стоит отвечать на вопросы. Без примеров и рассуждений, а конкретно. Повторяю: httр//сайт.ру/404.html - показывает содержимое этой страницы (404.html)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53204/discussion-between-alexan-dwer-and-sevlad).

Comment: Вы не против в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53204/discussion-between-alexan-dwer-and-sevlad) перейти?

Answer (score 0):

Правило в **.htaccess**:

```
...
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Файл **404.php**:

```
<?php
//
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//
echo $url;
?>
```

**P. S.** Если для профессионалы на Stack Overflow сочтут вопрос слишком простым, замечу, что поиск по нему не дал много информации. Возможно ответ слишком очевидный, но мне он сразу не пришёл на ум...